# How to stop Totem at last frame instead of rewinding?

Tags: video, settings, totem

I am asking a question which is similar to the one which has already been [asked in another place](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1322759) on 2009-11-11 by another person, and which has no reply.

I want to play a short video once, and then have it stop on the last frame. Then, I could press "p" again to play the clip once more, etc. In default, Totem rewinds to the first frame.

I know how to do this in VLC. But can this be done in Totem?

Answer (score 0):

The developers of Totem [informed me that as of now](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/totem/-/issues/468), they will not add this feature to Totem. I had asked the developers of Totem with the following rationale for this feature request:

Rationale

1. The last frame usually contains the written message of the video clip (like the "Moral Of The Story").
2. The last frame usually contains the facial expression of a person - an expression which is conclusive of the content of the video.
   In both these cases, being able to pause the last frame will help the viewers better grok the message or climax of the video clip.

After 3 months, they politely responded this:

> I don't think that's a use case we can cater for I'm afraid.

Comment: I have added the official statement from the developers. Is there anything else for me to add?